# Есть ли в Java что-то похожее на БСП от 1С

Tags: java, 1с

Есть ли в Java что-то похожее на `БСП` от `1С`.
В кратце про `БСП`.
`БСП` от `1С` - это готовые структуры баз данных, код, запросы и формы.

**Пример1.** Когда мне нужно сделать авторизацию пользователей я просто открываю `БСП` копипастю таблицу из готовой структуры базы данных код и формы для работы с этим и данный функционал готов к работе.

**Пример2.** `БСП` это как взять Вордпресс за основу и допилить его до кондиции. При этом не нужно разрабатывать некоторые мелочи типа регистрации пользователей.

Comment: БСП это механизм платформы, а не языка.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий, но я не утверждал ранее обратного. Хотя из вашей логики можно сделать вывод, что Вордпресс это механизм интерпретатора php, а не языка. Язык и есть механизм платформы. Хотя дальше продолжать дискуссию в этом направлении не вижу смысла. Если нужно уточнить по основному вопросу то с радостью. Мне просто не хочется изобретать велосипед на Java.

Comment: Я имею ввиду, что вы сравниваете несравнимое. Например где должен быть БСП в чипе банковской карты, запрограммированом на Java? А где БСП искать в движке полнотекстового поиска написанном на Java? Аналоги БСП могут быть в других ERP системах, но не в языке. Например, в SAP. Его можно программировать на Java и он ERP-платформа.

Comment: Ну, а если я хочу ERP платформу забомбить на Java. Но не хочу все делать с нуля. И хочу взять за основу некую программу написанную на Java неким чуваком. В этой программе должна быть реализована часть функционала который стандартен для всех ERPподобных систем. Зачем мне изобретать велосипед. А уже имея это я пойду дальше и заточу программу под свои нужны. Эту некую программу я и имел в виду спрашивая о подобии БСП написанной на Java, ведь БСП и есть такая программа написанная на 1С.

Answer (score 3):

Обратите внимание на Spring Data:
http://spring-projects.ru/guides/accessing-data-jpa/
https://habr.com/post/139421/
Достаточно описать сущность и отнаследовать интерфейс.

Comment: Да. Благодарю за ответ! Но я имел в виду нечто большее чем Spring. А именно некую программу имеющую в себе некоторую базовую функциональность написанную на Java. Как если бы взять Вордпресс и на его основе разработать нечно заточенное под конкретную предметную область. Но я не утверждаю, что такое есть на Яве. Просто интересуюсь ведь не могу утверждать обратного :)

Comment: Не могу подсказать ничего похожего под ваше описание.
Поиск в гугле дает например такой результат: https://toster.ru/q/349896
Для Spring есть достаточно большое количество туториалов, реализующих базовые вещи.